# Did the 5-minute "grace period" for editing questions or answers recently change or get removed?

Tags: support, editing, user-interface

Please refer to [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/86932/revisions).  I made 3 little edits in a three-minute period (timestamps 19:29:41Z, 19:30:48Z, 19:32:08Z).  In the olden days, this would be aggregated into one edit for the record.  Now it shows as 3 edits.

The only difference this makes is I will now try to be more careful before hitting the "Save edits" button.  But before I enjoyed the freedom to hit it and, if I discover a quick little typo or something I missed, to edit again, without this appearing as a separate edit.

Comment: I've been trying to see where that used to happen, and can't find it. Recently, when I edit and add a comment about the edit and then I edit soon again, the comment is put back in.  I'm wondering if that's the trigger: that there's a comment? [It certainly seems the 5 minute timeout used to be there.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77894/the-5min-timeout-should-be-reset-after-each-re-edit) But it doesn't mention merging edits.

Comment: Thanks for looking @PeterK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OK, I found the documentation in the FAQ.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

> Multiple edits made by the same person may be combined into a single
> revision, if they occur within a short period of time (currently 5
> minutes), unless the post is later edited by someone else or one of
> the events listed at the bottom occurs. Edits made by the original
> author are considered part of the base revision if submitted within 5
> minutes of posting (again, unless someone else edits the post or one
> of those events occurs) or migrating. This does not apply if the user
> doesn't have the remove new user restrictions privilege (awarded at 10
> reputation on all sites) - edits from these users will always create a
> new revision.

And then:

> ### Grace period
>
> In order to prevent a series of tiny edits from showing up in the
> revision history, a single user who makes a binding (not suggested)
> edit to a post is given a 5-minute grace period, except if one of the
> following conditions is true:
>
> - The previous revision was a rollback.
> - The new revision is a rollback (includes cases where one selects to edit a prior revision and doesn't make any changes).
> - The user does not have the remove new user restrictions privilege.
>
> During this period, any additional edits they make are collapsed into
> the same edit in the revision history, displaying only the final
> outcome of all their edits within that 5-minute period. The grace
> period ends after exactly 5 minutes, or if:
>
> - Another user edits the post, at which time their grace period begins.
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor (ignores deleted comments).
> - If the post being edited is a question and an answer has been added since the previous revision (ignores deleted answers but does
>   include answers by the editor).
> - The post is a question, and it has been closed since the previous revision.

Comment: Can you explain this, Peter?  I have three tiny edits made within 2 minutes and 38 seconds.  No one edited in the meantime.  Why aren't they merged into a single edit?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson No idea. Your edits run counter to this FAQ.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I'm not sure if there's a bug report on MSE about it, but I believe something did recently break with grace-period edits, causing them to no longer be listed as/combined into a single edit... I recall another CM mentioning it internally, at least.

Comment: Thank you @V2Blast .